# Bazel's container_pull failing to pull aws-cli image

Tags: docker, bazel, bazel-rules

tldr; When I try to pull an AWS-CLI image from Docker Hub using Bazel, I'm getting odd 404 errors. Pulling other images in the same way works fine.

I'm trying to use Bazel in my monorepo to (among many other things) create several Docker images. One of the Docker images I'm creating uses the verified [AWS CLI image](https://hub.docker.com/r/amazon/aws-cli/tags) as a base.

I'm following along with the [`rules_docker` documentation](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_docker/blob/master/README.md) along with [examples](https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_docker/tree/master/testing/examples) provided in that repo.

WORKSPACE File:

```
load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_file")

load("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_archive")

http_archive(
    name = "io_bazel_rules_docker",
    sha256 = "b1e80761a8a8243d03ebca8845e9cc1ba6c82ce7c5179ce2b295cd36f7e394bf",
    urls = ["https://github.com/bazelbuild/rules_docker/releases/download/v0.25.0/rules_docker-v0.25.0.tar.gz"],
)

load(
    "@io_bazel_rules_docker//repositories:repositories.bzl",
    container_repositories = "repositories",
)
container_repositories()

load("@io_bazel_rules_docker//repositories:deps.bzl", container_deps = "deps")

container_deps()

load(
    "@io_bazel_rules_docker//container:container.bzl",
    "container_pull",
)

load("@io_bazel_rules_docker//contrib:dockerfile_build.bzl", 
    "dockerfile_image")

container_pull(
    name = "alpine_linux_amd64",
    digest = "sha256:954b378c375d852eb3c63ab88978f640b4348b01c1b3456a024a81536dafbbf4",
    registry = "index.docker.io",
    repository = "library/alpine",
    # tag field is ignored since digest is set
    tag = "3.8",
)

container_pull(
    name = "aws_cli",
    digest = "sha256:abb7e318502e78ec99d85bfa0121d5fbc11d8c49bb95f7f12db0b546ebd5ff99",
    registry = "index.docker.io",
    repository = "library/amazon",
    # tag field is ignored since digest is set
    tag = "2.9.9",
)

http_file(
    name = "sam_archive",
    downloaded_file_path = "aws-sam-cli-linux-x86_64.zip",
    sha256 = "74264b224f133461e324e7877ed8218fe38ac2320ba498024f0c297de7bb3e95",
    urls = [
        "https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/releases/download/v1.67.0/aws-sam-cli-linux-x86_64.zip",
    ],
)
```

And BUILD file:

```
load("@io_bazel_rules_docker//container:container.bzl", "container_image", "container_layer")
load("@io_bazel_rules_docker//contrib:test.bzl", "container_test")
load("@io_bazel_rules_docker//docker/util:run.bzl", "container_run_and_commit")

# Includes the aws-cli installation archive
container_image(
    name = "aws_cli",
    base = "@aws_cli//image"
)

container_image(
    name = "basic_alpine",
    base = "@alpine_linux_amd64//image",
    cmd = ["Hello World!"],
    entrypoint = ["echo"],
)
```

Building `basic_alpine` works fine:

```
$ bazel build //:basic_alpine
INFO: Analyzed target //:basic_alpine (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured).
INFO: Found 1 target...
Target //:basic_alpine up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/basic_alpine-layer.tar
INFO: Elapsed time: 1.140s, Critical Path: 0.99s
INFO: 50 processes: 16 internal, 34 linux-sandbox.
INFO: Build completed successfully, 50 total actions
```

Admittedly new to Bazel and maybe I'm not doing this correctly, but building `aws_cli` fails:

```
$ bazel build //:aws_cli
INFO: Repository aws_cli instantiated at:
  /home/jdibling/repos/stream-ai.io/products/filedrop/monorepo/WORKSPACE:38:15: in <toplevel>
Repository rule container_pull defined at:
  /home/jdibling/.cache/bazel/_bazel_jdibling/4ce73e7de2c4ac9889a94fb9b2da25fc/external/io_bazel_rules_docker/container/pull.bzl:294:33: in <toplevel>
ERROR: An error occurred during the fetch of repository 'aws_cli':
   Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/home/jdibling/.cache/bazel/_bazel_jdibling/4ce73e7de2c4ac9889a94fb9b2da25fc/external/io_bazel_rules_docker/container/pull.bzl", line 240, column 13, in _impl
                fail("Pull command failed: %s (%s)" % (result.stderr, " ".join([str(a) for a in args])))
Error in fail: Pull command failed: 2022/12/23 08:31:25 Running the Image Puller to pull images from a Docker Registry...
2022/12/23 08:31:29 Image pull was unsuccessful: reading image "index.docker.io/library/amazon@sha256:abb7e318502e78ec99d85bfa0121d5fbc11d8c49bb95f7f12db0b546ebd5ff99": GET https://index.docker.io/v2/library/amazon/manifests/sha256:abb7e318502e78ec99d85bfa0121d5fbc11d8c49bb95f7f12db0b546ebd5ff99: UNAUTHORIZED: authentication required; [map[Action:pull Class: Name:library/amazon Type:repository]]
 (/home/jdibling/.cache/bazel/_bazel_jdibling/4ce73e7de2c4ac9889a94fb9b2da25fc/external/go_puller_linux_amd64/file/downloaded -directory /home/jdibling/.cache/bazel/_bazel_jdibling/4ce73e7de2c4ac9889a94fb9b2da25fc/external/aws_cli/image -os linux -os-version  -os-features  -architecture amd64 -variant  -features  -name index.docker.io/library/amazon@sha256:abb7e318502e78ec99d85bfa0121d5fbc11d8c49bb95f7f12db0b546ebd5ff99)
ERROR: /home/jdibling/repos/stream-ai.io/products/filedrop/monorepo/WORKSPACE:38:15: fetching container_pull rule //external:aws_cli: Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/home/jdibling/.cache/bazel/_bazel_jdibling/4ce73e7de2c4ac9889a94fb9b2da25fc/external/io_bazel_rules_docker/container/pull.bzl", line 240, column 13, in _impl
                fail("Pull command failed: %s (%s)" % (result.stderr, " ".join([str(a) for a in args])))
Error in fail: Pull command failed: 2022/12/23 08:31:25 Running the Image Puller to pull images from a Docker Registry...
2022/12/23 08:31:29 Image pull was unsuccessful: reading image "index.docker.io/library/amazon@sha256:abb7e318502e78ec99d85bfa0121d5fbc11d8c49bb95f7f12db0b546ebd5ff99": GET https://index.docker.io/v2/library/amazon/manifests/sha256:abb7e318502e78ec99d85bfa0121d5fbc11d8c49bb95f7f12db0b546ebd5ff99: UNAUTHORIZED: authentication required; [map[Action:pull Class: Name:library/amazon Type:repository]]
 (/home/jdibling/.cache/bazel/_bazel_jdibling/4ce73e7de2c4ac9889a94fb9b2da25fc/external/go_puller_linux_amd64/file/downloaded -directory /home/jdibling/.cache/bazel/_bazel_jdibling/4ce73e7de2c4ac9889a94fb9b2da25fc/external/aws_cli/image -os linux -os-version  -os-features  -architecture amd64 -variant  -features  -name index.docker.io/library/amazon@sha256:abb7e318502e78ec99d85bfa0121d5fbc11d8c49bb95f7f12db0b546ebd5ff99)
ERROR: /home/jdibling/repos/stream-ai.io/products/filedrop/monorepo/BUILD:6:16: //:aws_cli depends on @aws_cli//image:image in repository @aws_cli which failed to fetch. no such package '@aws_cli//image': Pull command failed: 2022/12/23 08:31:25 Running the Image Puller to pull images from a Docker Registry...
2022/12/23 08:31:29 Image pull was unsuccessful: reading image "index.docker.io/library/amazon@sha256:abb7e318502e78ec99d85bfa0121d5fbc11d8c49bb95f7f12db0b546ebd5ff99": GET https://index.docker.io/v2/library/amazon/manifests/sha256:abb7e318502e78ec99d85bfa0121d5fbc11d8c49bb95f7f12db0b546ebd5ff99: UNAUTHORIZED: authentication required; [map[Action:pull Class: Name:library/amazon Type:repository]]
 (/home/jdibling/.cache/bazel/_bazel_jdibling/4ce73e7de2c4ac9889a94fb9b2da25fc/external/go_puller_linux_amd64/file/downloaded -directory /home/jdibling/.cache/bazel/_bazel_jdibling/4ce73e7de2c4ac9889a94fb9b2da25fc/external/aws_cli/image -os linux -os-version  -os-features  -architecture amd64 -variant  -features  -name index.docker.io/library/amazon@sha256:abb7e318502e78ec99d85bfa0121d5fbc11d8c49bb95f7f12db0b546ebd5ff99)
ERROR: Analysis of target '//:aws_cli' failed; build aborted: Analysis failed
INFO: Elapsed time: 4.171s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (0 packages loaded, 0 targets configured)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick sanity check - should that be `library/amazonlinux`? AFAICT `library/amazon` does not exist. However, that one does not have a tag with the sha265 that you specify.

The link you have in the intro is for the `amazon/aws-cli` image, which does have that [tag](https://hub.docker.com/layers/amazon/aws-cli/2.9.9/images/sha256-abb7e318502e78ec99d85bfa0121d5fbc11d8c49bb95f7f12db0b546ebd5ff99?context=explore), so maybe that's the one that you mean to pull?